# remove endashes at linebreaks

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I want to typeset a paragraph of endash-separated expressions, like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\centering 
test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test -- test

\end{document}
```

However, I don't want the endashes to be printed as first or last items in a line - in a way, I want them to behave like spacing commands (blank, `\hfil`, `\hfill`, `\hfilll`).

So instead of this

```
test - test - test -
test - test - test
```

or this

```
test - test - test
- test - test - test
```

I want this

```
test - test - test
test - test - test
```

Please note that I want this to happen automatically, without having to fix each line manually

How can this be achieved?

Comment: May I ask why you need this feature? Perhaps what you want to achieve could be done through other means? If this is just an en-dash separated list, I am not sure removing the dashes is the best typographical choice – but I hope a wizard can conjure up something for you.

Comment: I'm writing a dictionary-like document, where each entry consists of a heading and a short description paragraph. However, the heading already contains different information snippets, that should be separated somehow. I decided that a simple comma didn't yield sufficient visual separation, so I decided for an endash. However, the thing is two-col, and for some entries, the headlines already span several lines. But leading/trailing endashes look stupid, specially since their only purpos is visual separation. Hence my request :-)

Comment: Well, you've already got your answer by the looks of it... But perhaps different solutions can be found in large dictionaries with similar problems (in my uneerstanding, though, they put the info snippets after the heading). It depends on your needs of course, but gerenally speaking typographic separators are also seen as grammatical separators (i.e. they have a meaning for the reader despite visual separation). Then again, perhaps your solution is the best one for what you want to produce.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TeX has a facility for things that "behave like space" namely *leaders*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newsavebox\zz
\savebox\zz{--}
\def\foo{\cleaders\copy\zz\hskip1.9\wd\zz}
\begin{document}
\centering 

test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test\foo test

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\newcommand*\foo{ \cleaders\copy\zz\hskip\wd\zz\relax\space}` the spaces keep their stretchability.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes although as centering all the stretch is at the margins anyway.